# jQuery - struggling with undefined variable

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, attr

I've tried to get the attribute value of a html tag with jquery.

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM frontpage_modules";
        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        $result = mysql_query($query) or (mysql_error());
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $list[] = $row['module_name'];
            $name[] = $row['name'];
            $img[] = $row['img'];
            $link[] = $row['link'];
            $module_content[] = $row['module_content'];
        }
    ?>


  <form action="ChangeFrontpageModule.php" method="post">  
   <ul id="gallery">
            <?php

                for ($idx = 0; $idx < count($list); $idx+=1) {
                    echo "<li data-itemid='" . $idx . "'>";
                    echo "<div class='drag_div'>";


                    echo '<div class="kundeutsagn">';
                    echo '<img src="http://www.amedisin.no/pictures/artikler/'.$img[$idx].'" alt="Top5"  title="Top5" />';
                    echo '<div class="statement_top">';
                    echo '<h5>'.$name[$idx].'</h5>';
                    echo "<input type='text' name='title' value='".$name[$idx]."' />";
                    echo $module_content[$idx];
                    echo '</div></div>';


                    echo "</div>";
                    echo "</li>";
                }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

I'm trying to pass the an id which is stored in the data-itemid (within the li) and the value in the input element.

I'm able to get the data from the input element though this code "var title = $(this).val();", but the attribute value returnes an error "undefined"

Below is the jquery script that returns an error

```
   <script>
        $(function() {
    $('h5').click(function() {
        $(this).slideUp().next('input').slideDown();
    });
    $('ul#gallery input').change(function() {
        var id = $(this).parent('li').attr('data-itemid');
        var thisParam = $(this);
        var title = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'JavaScript/ChangeFrontpageModule.php',
            data: 'title=' + title + '&id=' + id,
            success: function(response) {
                $('input').slideUp();
                $(thisParam).prev('h5').text(title).slideDown();
                $('#response').fadeIn(1000).empty().append(response).prepend('<span id="x">X</span>');
                $('span#x').click(function() {
                    $('div#response').fadeOut('slow');
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
        </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for the `data-itemid` attribute from `$(this).parent('ul')`, but the attribute in the first snippet you posted is on the `<li>` elements, not on the `<ul>`.

**Edit**: Taking a closer look, the `input` is also not a direct descendant of the `li`. Use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead.

So if you switch `$(this).parent('li')` to `$(this).closest('li')` you should be fine.

**Credit** to @wirey's comment for `closest()`, I had mistakenly suggested `parents()`

Comment: @Chris Indeed I missed a spot. Took a closer look and updated, hopefully it'll work.

Comment: .parents() will select all `li` parents to be clear, so if you had nested `ul`'s, you would get multiple `li`'s,  .closest() would probably be better

Comment: @wirey Updated the answer with credit, but you got it right first, if you want to post it as an answer I'll get mine out of the way.

Comment: @Rick No it's fine.  You had the right answer according to his example, but just saying it would be safest to use .closest() :)

Comment: @Rick and wirey - Thanks for the help - you found the issue. THANKS